# Learning Spring-mvc and need knowledge on Odds and Ends of The Spring Framework that require prerequisite knowledge

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

So I have limited experience in JSP and Servlets. I am learning the spring framework specifically Spring MVC but I see there is some prerequisite knowledge required to properly use the spring framework. 
I understand dependency injection using spring. A spring configuration file with bean declarations makes sense to me. And that file is the mvc-dispatcher.xml file. But what else is commonly needed in a web.xml other than the DispatcherServlet declaration? In a web.xml of a project I am studying, I see there is an unfamiliar item called a `<listener>` and `<context-param>`. What are these entries in the web.xml for? What is the need for `contextConfigLocation`?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml  /WEB-INF/plugins.xml /WEB-INF/spring-ext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

servlet is to register a servlet instance.  In this case, you're creating spring's dispatcher servlet, which you'll configure later.

servlet-mapping will mapp url patterns to a specific servlet.  In your case you're registering / to your spring servlet, meaning spring will handle all of the requests that come into your application.

listener registers a listener with the servlet container that responds to servlet context events.  The ContextLoaderListener responds to the servlet being loaded by instantiating a spring context.  The  with param-name of "contextConfigLocation" is used by this listener to find the spring .xml files which will be used to construct the context.

Do yourself a favor and go to the spring documentation for a tutorial on getting started, as the contents of those xml files and the proper configuration is well documented.

Also, this configuration is not going to work completely anyway, as the servlet itself will look for a servlet-mvc-dispatcher.xml file to configure the mvc part of spring (you can override this, but that's it's default behavior).  What's in "contextConfigLocation" is the main application context and the servlet-mvc-dispatcher.xml becomes a child context of that.

Comment: Im going through spring in action book. Do you think I could gain further benefit from visiting the spring docs? Why?

Comment: Spring in Action should likely cover it.  Had i known you were reading that, i would have suggested reading a bit more before trying to implement something :)  There's a lot in the mvc framework, but the three basic files you need to worry about is the web.xml, the servlet-<servlet-name>.xml and your applicationContext.xml file.